# Eigen value and transpose of the $Matrix$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ and $B$ are linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb R$ such that $(AB)^2 = AB$ and $BA$ is invertible , then which of the following are true ?
>
> 1. $AB = BA$ on $V$.
> 2. $ Tr (A)$ is non zero
> 3. $0$ is an eigen value of $B$
> 4. $1$ is an eigen value of$A$

Since $BA$ is invertible , then $A$ and $B$ are invertible , and eigen value of $AB$ are $0$ and $1$ and $AB$ is dioganlizabe , because minimal polynomial of $AB$ is $x^2 -x = 0 $, and we know that the eigen value of $AB$ and $BA$ are same counted with the multiplecity of non -zeroeigen value and $BA$ is invertible . So the eigen value of $BA$ is $1$ with multiplecity $n$.

I am confused. my concept is contradicting.please give a me way how to solve.

Thank you.

Comment: Which linear operator has eigenvalue $1$ with geometric multiplicity $\dim V$? What is then the relation between $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @ Levap   : $AB$ has eigen value $1$ with multiplicity   $dim \ V$

Answer (score 3):

$A$ and $B$ are square matrices. Since $BA$ is invertible, $A$ and $B$ are both invertible, because $\det(B)\det(A)=\det(BA)\neq 0$.

Thus $ABAB=AB$ implies $AB=I$, and $B$ is the inverse of $A$, thus $AB=BA=I$.

Since $B$ is invertible, it does not have $0$ as an eigenvalue.

You can't say anything about (2) and (4) because all invertible matrices $A$ satisfy your conditions. And of course, not all invertible matrice satisfy (2) or (4), though some do (for example the identity matrix).

A trivial counter example to (2) is a [permutation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) associated to a [derangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) (thus only $0$s on the diagonal). A trivial counter example to (4) is any multiple $aI$ of the identity matrix with $a\neq 1$.

Comment: @ Jean : what can you say about the polylomial $x^2 -x$ which divides the characterstic polynomian of $AB$

Comment: @user120386 Wrong, since $AB=I$ and the characteristic polynomial is thus $(x-1)^n$. You have never proved that $x^2-x$ is the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @ Jean : thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: @user120386 Actually, what is troublesome here: if $P(A)=0$, then it's a multiple of a *minimal polynomial* (say $Q$), because $\Bbb R[X]$ is a principal ring, and polynomials $P$ such that $P(A)=0$ obviously constitute an ideal. But, given *some* polynomial $P$ such that $P(A)=0$, you only know that $P$ is a multiple of $Q$.

Answer (score 2):

can we do this?  it looks like $AB = I.$ here is the reason. we have $$I = (AB)^2 =  ABAB = AB$$ multiplying by $A$ on the right and $(BA)^{-1}$ on the left  gives us $$ABA(BA)(BA)^{-1}=A(BA)(BA)^{-1}\to ABA = A \to (BA)^2 = (BA) $$ and that $BA$ is invertible implies that only eigenvalues of $BA$ is $1.$

i think $(BA)^2 = BA$ and $1$ is the only eigenvalue must imply  that $$BA = I $$ which in turn give $AB = I.$